# How to set a default handler for "CSRF verification failed" in django?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views), we can set the a default error handler like this:

```
handler403 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_permission_denied_view'
...
```

My handler for 404 and 500 is working fine. But in case of access forbidden, I can't trigger it (when I raise `HttpResponseForbidden`, the triggered handler is the handler for error 500). Anyway, that's not my problem. My problem is when I try to tamper (for testing purposes) the `CSRF` token, it throws "Forbidden" but again, my handler for access forbidden is not invoked - it invokes the default django template for 403 forbidden. And when I try to access the root directory of `static` (or `media`) directory, the invoked page is from the servers default forbidden page (apache httpd in my case) which is fine.

My question is:

- How to set default handler for "CSRF verification failed"?
- What are the cases that the 403 handler is being called?
- How can I trigger a 403 forbidden error?

Here is my setup:

- Python 3.4
- Django 1.10 (production, debug = False)
- Server: Apache httpd through mod_wsgi
- Windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do, in settings

```
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'your_app_name.views.csrf_failure'
```

in view

```
def csrf_failure(request, reason=""):
    ctx = {'message': 'some custom messages'}
    return render(request, your_custom_template, ctx)
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW

(found it in the link you provided)

It looks that CSRF is handled little differently in django - and it is not standard handler403;